# How to rebase master branch into current branch but behind it?

Tags: git

Suppose branches look like this

```
master: A B C D*
           \  
my-branch:  E F G H*
```

I want it to look like this

```
master: A B C D*
               \
my-branch:      E F G H*
```

Comment: Side note: a branch name identifies the *last* commit in the branch, not the first. The first commit in branch `my-branch` is commit `A`. Commit `A` is also the first commit in branch `master`. That commit is in both branches. When the rebase is done, you have four new commits: the original four `E-F-G-H` commits still exist and `E`'s parent is still `B`, so the name `my-branch` identifies the *copy* of commit `H`. If we call that one H-prime (`H'`), the name `my-branch` locates `H'`, which locates `G'`, which locates `F'`, which locates `E'`, which locates `D`.

Comment: so rebase duplicates all those commits? but oldest commit parent is changed?

Comment: Yes. Rebase *must* copy a commit in order to make *any* change at all to it, because the commit's hash ID is a checksum of the commit's content. Change the content and you have a new, different commit, with a new, different hash ID. Rebase needs to make `E'` different from `E` in two ways: it has a different parent, and it has (probably anyway) a different snapshot (assuming the snapshot in `D` differs from that in `B`).

Comment: checksum also includes parent commit's hash? otherwise content isn't chaning

Comment: Yes. Technically it's a checksum of the metadata; the snapshot uses a Git *tree* object and is specified via the metadata. The metadata of any commit is all human-readable: try `git cat-file -p HEAD` to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebase master on your branch, then merge your branch into master.

```
git checkout my-branch
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge my-branch
```

Comment: Master never moved in OP's example

Comment: this will need to happen eventually but not now

Answer (score 9):

Just rebase your branch onto master:

```
git checkout my-branch
git rebase master
```

Comment: or just do it by one command: `git rebase master my-branch` which is effectively doing the above 2 commands.